# How to use xml-printf to extract values from multiple elements?

Tags: xml, xpath

For the following example, I want to extract the result and print it in the following way.

```
ID1<TAB>Text1
ID2<TAB>Text2
```

But I cannot find the right command. Does anybody know what is the best command to print the output in the following way?

```
~$ cat xxx.xml
<a>
<b>
  <c>ID1</c>
  <d>
   <e>Text1</e>
  </d>
</b>
<b>
  <c>ID2</c>
  <d>
   <e>Text2</e>
  </d>
</b>
</a>
~$ xml-printf '%s\t%s\n' xxx.xml :/a/b/c :/a/b/d/e
ID1
ID2    Text1
Text2
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple `b` elements; you can iterate over them and use `xml-printf` to format each,

```
$ for i in {1..2}; do xml-printf '%s\t%s\n' xxx.xml :/a/b[$i]/c :/a/b[$i]/d/e; done
ID1 Text1
ID2 Text2
$
```

as requested.